# Find Maximum number of days to open the lock

Tags: combinatorics, logic, permutations

A child attempts to open a five disc lock. He takes $5$ seconds to dial a particular number on the disc. if he does so for $5 $hours every day, Find Max number of days he would take to open the lock.

My Try: Since it is dial disc, total possible $5$ digit codes is $10^5$.

Since he takes $25$ seconds to dial a $5$ digit code, number of $5$ digit codes he tried in one day is $\frac{5 \times 60 \times 60}{25}=720$

Let $n$ be number of days, so

$$720n=10^5$$ $\implies$

$n=139$ days approx. But my book answer is $666$

Please tell where i went wrong?

Comment: Does he try a distinct combination every attempt?

Comment: that is not specified in the question. I assumed it

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.  The first is that the problem statement says it takes $5$ seconds to try a number, which I read as inputting all five characters.  You have used $25$ thinking that it takes $5$ seconds to set each of $5$ characters.  That is an English question, not a mathematical one.  The second is there is nothing in the question as you have quoted it that tells us how many numbers are on the disc.  As I read it he can try $3600$ codes per day.  If I go backwards from the answer to ask the number of characters $k$ in the combination I am trying to solve $3600 \cdot 666=k^5$ then round up and I get [$k=19$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3600%20*666%3Dx%5E5) which is a strange number of characters to use in the combination.  In your reading I get $14$ characters to compensate for the fact that he doesn't try codes as fast.  That is also a strange number to use in the combination.  You are thinking correctly.

Comment: Also, any reasonable person would probably try 00000, 00001, 00002, etc. so you don't have to change all 5 discs every time ... but that would decrease the time even more ...